# Creating a multipage website without loading

Tags: html, web, loading

So i am trying to create a website with multiple different pages. I was originally going to just take the traditional route but this website caught my eye: https://anyoneworldwide.com/

Everything aside from the "Choose your location" screen has no loading whatsoever. The URL changes but there is no loading indicator on my tab or "X" on the refresh button (I am using chrome btw)

So my question is; how am I able to use this kind loading technique in a website of my own?

Comment: lord, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be sure to research your questions before posting. You can find an answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 2):

The particular website mentioned in the question is developed using React. Its a javascript framework.The concept is know as Single Page Application. Where routing is done by javascript running in the browser and content is loaded using ajax calls. checkout [this](https://medium.com/@pshrmn/a-simple-react-router-v4-tutorial-7f23ff27adf) article.

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer, pick one of the currently popular front end frameworks for building single page apps (SPA).

E.g. AngularJs, React.js, vue.js

These frameworks allow you to easily create client side routers, which inject (in one way or another) new content into the existing page, thus no refresh.

Answer (score 0):

React is a popular open source and free library developed by facebook. It is used to develop single page applications which means that your website wont load at all. This increased the speed of your website and saves a lot of bandwidth. Using react you can make such a website as you mentioned. Not only React but also other frameworks like angular and Vuejs can be used.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30395230)